# What are the parts of and how is a raw coin generation transaction made?

Tags: transactions, mining-reward, raw-transaction

Referencing: https://blockchain.info/tx/9b0fc92260312ce44e74ef369f5c66bbb85848f2eddd5a7a1cde251e54ccfdd5

With raw data:

> 01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0704ffff001d010bffffffff0100f2052a010000004341047211a824f55b505228e4c3d5194c1fcfaa15a456abdf37f9b9d97a4040afc073dee6c89064984f03385237d92167c13e236446b417ab79a0fcae412ae3316b77ac00000000

This appears to differ greatly from a regular transaction and appears to have different parts.  What are those parts broken up and how does one acquire them?  Which part is hashed? etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal transaction will have previously unspent outputs listed as inputs, but a coinbase transaction is different. A coinbase transaction will always have a single input, called a *coinbase*, that follows a specific format.
 [An overview of the transaction specification can be found here.](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format)

I've copied the example from that page below for convenience:

```
An itemized coinbase transaction:

01000000 .............................. Version

01 .................................... Number of inputs

| 00000000000000000000000000000000
| 00000000000000000000000000000000 ...  Previous outpoint TXID
| ffffffff ............................ Previous outpoint index
|
| 29 .................................. Bytes in coinbase
| |
| | 03 ................................ Bytes in height
| | | 4e0105 .......................... Height: 328014
| |
| | 062f503253482f0472d35454085fffed
| | f2400000f90f54696d65202620486561
| | 6c74682021 ........................ Arbitrary data
| 00000000 ............................ Sequence

01 .................................... Output count
| 2c37449500000000 .................... Satoshis (25.04275756 BTC)
| 1976a914a09be8040cbf399926aeb1f4
| 70c37d1341f3b46588ac ................ P2PKH script
| 00000000 ............................ Locktime
```